# Append Const Char to Char* C++

Tags: c++, string, char

I know this sounds like a beginner question but I have never worked with char* in c++. I always just used strings. But there is a bug with `Ubuntu 13.10` and the `NVidia` `OpenGL` drivers so I have to use char*. [Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-319/+bug/1248642) is the bug.

I have a class that takes a `const char* folderName` in the constructor and then creates compiles all the `.glsl` files in the folder. I have tried `strcpy` and `strcat` and they both seem so override.

```
glProgram *p = new glProgram("phong\n");
glProgram :: glProgram(const char* folderName)
{
    cout << folderName << endl;
    char* name = strdup(folderName);
    cout << name << endl;
    name = strcat(name,"/vertex.glsl");     
    cout << name << endl;
}
```

But the output is not as expected.

```
phong
phong
/vertex.glsl
```

How can I get the output to be `phong/vertex.glsl`?

Comment: You should not be using `strdup` to allocate the new string, it won't be big enough to hold the larger result. Other than that I can't explain your output.

Comment: There is a newline character in your folder name. Are you sure that isn't why  you think they aren't being concatenated? Also, you used `strdup` to copy the folder name and then `strcat` to concatenate the folder name and file name. There is no way you can guarantee there is enough space in `name` for the concatenation if you do it that way.

Comment: you mean `const char *a="one"; const char *b="two";size_t len1 = strlen(a);size_t len2 = strlen(b); char *buff = new char[len1+len2+1]; strcpy(buff,a);strcat(buff,b);`? Also, don't forget to delete the allocated space.

Comment: why not just use `string` and if you need a `char*` call `c_str`?

Comment: @PeterT Thank you that worked. I also needed to remove the `\n` from the first string

Comment: @anonymous: The problem here is that you didn't bother to read the question or follow the link provided. The OP simply cannot do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is invalid because you overwrite memory that does not belong to the dynamically allocated array. You should yourself allocate a memory region large enough to contain the concatenated string.

```
glProgram *p = new glProgram("phong\n");

glProgram :: glProgram(const char *folderName)
{
    const char *vertex = "/vertex.glsl";

    size_t n = std::strlen( folderName );
    if ( n != 0 && folderName[n - 1] == '\n' ) --n;

    char *name = new char[n + std::strlen( vertex ) + 1];

    std::strncpy( name, folderName, n );
    name[n] = '\0';
    std::strcat( name, vertex ); 
}
```

Also I do not see any sense that the argument includes the new line character. Why may not the argument look as `"phong"`?

Comment: Thank you that worked. Removing the `\n` from the argument is better.